# Why can’t I be made admin on Telegram?

Tags: admin, telegram, administrator

I’m a member of a Telegram Channel. The owner and administrator asked if I would admin for him. He wanted to promote 3 of us to admin. He successfully promoted the other two members. The app will not allow him to promote me. We have no idea why and cannot find any information online about such a problem.

I have tried changing my settings in myriad ways and making sure that we are in each others contacts. I have created my own channel without issue and I am admin of that channel.

I have searched the internet as best as I know how.

You are my only hope.

Comment: This isn't the right place for this type of question. Contact Telegram support or consider asking this question on reddit.

Comment: use quora to find solution or medium.com

Comment: There is no Telegram support.